# Jmeter HTTP request java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 71

Tags: http-post, jmeter

It's the first time I'm encountering this error for HTTP request (POST).

I'm trying to do a simple post request, not sure why it doesn't work using the `Jmeter`.

please help :-)

---

### URL:

> https://connect-qa.bglobale.com:4453/Checkout/SendCart?shippingDetails={"CountryCode":"LI"}&clientIP=79.120.71.29&priceCoefficientRate=1&includeVAT=0&discountsList={"DiscountValue":29.028122604,"OriginalDiscountValue":122.838,"Name":"Cart Discount","DiscountType":1,"VATRate":18}&merchantCartToken=1294&currencyCode=CHF&originalCurrencyCode=ILS&cultureCode=en-GB&preferedCultureCode=en_US&shippingOptionsList={"Carrier":"flatrate","CarrierTitle":"Flat Rate","CarrierName":"Flat Rate","Code":"flatrate_flatrate","Method":"flatrate","MethodTitle":"Fixed","MethodDescription":null,"Price":0}&hubId=1&merchantGUID=0f4eec24-8988-4361-be9a-a7468d05f1fe

### Headers:

> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

### Body:

```js
[
   {
      "ProductCode":"7290012491047",
      "ProductGroupCode":null,
      "Name":"Natural and Organic Calendula Shampoo 400ml",
      "Keywords":null,
      "ProductURL":null,
      "Description":"Natural and Organic Calendula Shampoo 400ml",
      "GenericHSCode":"",
      "Weight":"0.5000",
      "Height":null,
      "Length":null,
      "Width":null,
      "Volume":null,
      "ImageURL":"/c/a/calendula_shampoo.jpg",
      "ImageWidth":"",
      "ImageHeight":"",
      "OriginCountryCode":"",
      "ListPrice":"8.90",
      "OriginalListPrice":"47.2",
      "SalePrice":"8.90",
      "OriginalSalePrice":"47.2",
      "UnitSalePriceForDuties":null,
      "OriginalSalePriceAfterGlobalEDiscount":null,
      "VATRateType":{
         "VATRateTypeCode":"2",
         "Name":"VAT",
         "Rate":18
      },
      "Brand":null,
      "Categories":[
         {
            "CategoryCode":"4",
            "Name":"Baby"
         },
         {
            "CategoryCode":"18",
            "Name":"Calendula"
         },
         {
            "CategoryCode":"20",
            "Name":"Chamomile"
         },
         {
            "CategoryCode":"24",
            "Name":"​Coconut Oil"
         },
         {
            "CategoryCode":"26",
            "Name":"Geranium Oil"
         },
         {
            "CategoryCode":"29",
            "Name":"Jojoba"
         },
         {
            "CategoryCode":"30",
            "Name":"Lavender"
         },
         {
            "CategoryCode":"38",
            "Name":"Rosemary"
         },
         {
            "CategoryCode":"39",
            "Name":"Sea Buckthorn"
         },
         {
            "CategoryCode":"42",
            "Name":"Soapwort"
         },
         {
            "CategoryCode":"45",
            "Name":"Sunflower Oil"
         }
      ],
      "OrderedQuantity":1,
      "IsBlockedForGlobalE":null
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you're receiving indicates that you're sending a `GET` request, not `POST`. Make sure that you have selected `POST` method in HTTP Sampler.

You may also find [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) guide useful.